# What is the best way to get my test questions from a Word document into an online assessment tool?

Tags: exams, software, tools, assessment, automation

Since the pandemic, my department has been encouraging faculty to shift their assessments online. I've been holding off because I've heard from others how laborious it is to enter my test questions into our LMS (we use Blackboard), and I store my test questions in a Word document. I'm open to other solutions and not entirely tied to Blackboard.

What kind of software or workaround have you found for this problem?

Comment: For your students' sake, please stick with the LMS the rest of their classes are in.

Comment: I think @AzorAhai-him-'s comment should be taken as dictum.  OP must use the provided LMS.  However, there hypothetically could exist LMS plugins that facilitate moving questions from Word to the LMS.  Also in theory it is a competitive market and the LMS wants to retain your university as a client.  Ask them (or your university's contact with them).  They may have tools for this.  Help them help you help them retain your university's income stream.

Answer (score 4):

At Michigan, it wasn't very sophisticated.  We tended to use Google docs to develop our test questions so the entire staff could contribute.  Once it was soup, we just did a lot of copying and pasting into the exam system (for us, it was Gradescope or a homegrown system called Crabster.)  Sometimes I did the copying and pasting myself, other times I simply assigned one of my staff.  YMMV.

Comment: @Buffy [Crabster](https://tinyurl.com/CrabsterBreakout) was a randomized exam server my staff created.  Every student saw a different exam, making it difficult to collaborate.

Comment: In our EECS 280 C++ class we had cartoon mascots on our staff tee shirts. A lot of them were lobsters, a play on "Labster", an interactive tool for animating and teaching C++ that had been written by one of the instructors. Later, we moved on to crab mascots.